# Number of ways to distribute $n$ items to $k$ groups given number of items required for each group.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem goes as follows:

> we have 20 workers and we need to distribute them to 4 departments,
> department 1 needs 6 workers, department 2 needs 4 workers, department
> 3 needs 5 workers, department 4 needs 5 workers, by how many ways can
> distribute these workers?

My attempt:

> since workers are not identical so the order is important then the
> answer should be   = $$4^6 \times 3^4 \times 2^5 \times1^5$$

but I do not believe that to be the correct answer as one department can have the same workers but different order and still be considered another way to arrange the workers,

> I tried fixing this by dividing by possible arrangments of workers in
> each department
>
> = $$(4^6 \times 3^4 \times 2^5 \times1^5) \over 6! \times  4! \times5!  \times 5!$$ $$$$

I ended up having a decimal number so my answer is of course incorrect

what has gone wrong? is my intuition incorrect?

thanks in advance.

> NOTE: I know the problem is not the same as what the title says but I
> wanted to **generalize**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that when you do $4^6$ you are essentially taking $6$ workers out of nowhere to place them in one of the $4$ departments. This never guaranties that you have $6$ workers in the first department.

**Edit:** When you do $4^6$ means that you are going to list tuples of length $6$ where each entry can have one of $4$ values. So you are counting $(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6)$ where $d_i$ is the department in which the $i-$th person is working. Notice that these $6$ people are not specified, so you have to specify them by **picking** them. Furthermore, when you pick them, nothing guarantees that you will choose the tuple $(4,4,4,4,4,4)$ so in these arrangement you have put all your six workers in the department 4 (but this is not possible because department $4$ has just $5$ people).

The correct approach is, you have your workers, then lets say you want to build department $1,$ then you **choose** $6$ workers out of the total $20$ in $\binom{20}{6}$ ways. How many workers are left? $20-6,$ now choose the workers for department $2.$ Use the multiplication principle.
You should get something like $$\binom{20}{6}\binom{14}{4}\binom{10}{5}=\frac{20!}{6!\cdot 4!\cdot 5!\cdot 5!}.$$

Comment: how am i taking 6 workers out of nowhere when using $4^6$ , can you elaborate? i thought $4^6$ meant that the first 6 workers can have any of the four departments.

Comment: @AmirWG I have edited to explain better what $4^6$ means.

Comment: i get you now , thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @AmirWG You are welcome.